# Heroku release fail : libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku, django-rest-framework, vtk

I've got a problem when I'm trying to deploy a django rest framework app on Heroku.

When it comes to the release, I've got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vtk/vtkOpenGLKit.py", line 5, in <module>
from .vtkOpenGLKitPython import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ ... ]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkOpenGLKitPython'
```

Here is my Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn orthoinback.wsgi
```

My heroku-env

```
PYTHONPATH=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

and my [requirements.txt](https://pastebin.com/raw/0PnnPFLH) (pastebin link)

I'd like to know if I missed something or did something wrong.
Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use opencv-python-headless as it is out of libSM6 dependency. so use this it will solve your problem.

```
opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32
```